# Where to eat cheap authentic laksa in Kuala Lumpur?

Tags: food-and-drink, local-cuisine, kuala-lumpur

One of my favourite foods is laksa. In Australia it's often served in Thai restaurants or noodle bars, but apparently it's actually from Singapore and Malaysia.

So now I'm in KL and I want to indulge in laksa. But I'm staying in Chinatown and so far only found laksa in one place. I want to try a good variety rather so need to find some more.

I don't want a recommendation for your favourite laksa place, I want to know generally how to find places that serve it. Also I like cheap unpretentious places - streetside, plastic tables etc are all fine.

So is there an area of KL with lots of Malay restaurants or places that specialize in laksa? Or is there some food chain with laksa and branches everywhere? Or should I try shopping mall food courts? Or is it so ubiquitous that they don't usually bother writing "laksa" on a sign since locals know all Malaysian food places will have it?

Comment: This article maybe helpful http://www.xcelhotelrajachulan.com/2013/01/best-curry-laksa-in-kuala-lumpur/

Comment: @Simon: That article contains some handy tips, like that *laksa* refers to a certain kind of noode rather than the dish as a whole as in English. So I can keep an eye out for "curry noodles" and "curry mee" now. I walked many hours today and settled for Indian and Chinese meals, so laksa is definitely not easy to find for a naive westerner (-:

Comment: I hope it helps, I think its names specific places in KL. Also don't forget to try Beef Rendang & Roti Canai, these are other popular Malay dishes that I have tried.

Comment: Curry mee is *not* the same dish as laksa: *mee* are yellow egg noodles, whereas laksa is specifically rice noodles (usually anyway!), and the soup is basically diluted chicken curry missing the essential kick of laksa leaf.

Comment: Funny I asked my local friend whether *laksa* meant a kind of noodle or a kind of dish or preparation and surprisingly he said it was a type of dish but that it usually came with its "proper type" of noodle. He's not Malay but Chinese Malaysian then again his parents run a restaurant ... Oh so laksa is a leaf? Interesting!

Comment: Laksa noodles = white, cylindrical, roughly spaghetti-sized rice noodles.  Laksa leaf (*daun laksa*) = the herb *Persicaria odorata*, known as laksa leaf in Malaysia/Singapore because that's pretty much the only dish it's used in.  (In Vietnam, though, it's everywhere.)

Answer (score 10):

As you've already found out, laksa is not a single dish, but a constellation of them -- there's something like a dozen major varieties in Malaysia alone, plus those in Singapore, Indonesia, etc.  Wikipedia has a [pretty exhaustive rundown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laksa).  Somewhat oddly, Kuala Lumpur does *not* have its own variety, which explains why you're not seeing laksa joints around every corner the way you would in eg. Singapore.

Australian laksa is usually closest to *laksa lemak*, a curry-based laksa with coconut milk (*lemak* in this case means coconut cream), which is mostly associated with Singapore.  *Katong laksa*, after the Singapore district of Katong, is particularly well-known:

[image]
(courtesy me!)

Note the sparse toppings compared to the Aussie style of chucking in anything and everything: a real Katong laksa has only a few slices of fish cake and some raw cockles (shudder) or prawns (my preference!).

The other major style is *assam laksa* (lit. sour laksa or tamarind laksa), which uses sour tamarind paste instead of coconut milk plus stirs in ground fish.  It tastes very different, and is often very spicy, but it's also quite addictive when you get used to it.  It's a specialty of Penang.

[image]
([courtesy MichaelJLowe / Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Penang_laksa.jpg))

And then you've got Sarawak laksa, a crazy blend of the two; Johor laksa made with Italian spaghetti (I kid you not!), Kelantam *laksam* (not a typo), which has wide fettucini-style rice noodles in a mild coconutty stew instead of a soup, Betawi laksa with bits of intestines floating about (don't worry, you won't find this outside Jakarta), etc etc.

One good place to try these all is the [Laksa Shack](http://www.laksashack.com/) chain, which has outlets in many of Kuala Lumpur's malls, including the food court at KLCC (below Petronas Towers).  Their website is useless, but all they do is laksa in a dozen or so varieties.  Compared to Jalan Alor, there's not much in the way of ambience, but the food's pretty cheap and authentic (around RM10 a bowl, IIRC) and air-con comes in handy if you tackle their assam laksa!  The Kelantanese sit-down restaurant on the top floor of KLCC also does a pretty mean *laksam*.

Comment: My local friend was talking about Laksa Shack but after scouting many restaurants which were not open we ended up at Old Town Coffee which despite its name had a fantastic Assam laksa.

Comment: I went into various random older malls with restaurants in them in the "shopping district" and found no Laksa Shack so far...

Comment: @hippietrail According to http://www.laksashack.com/ they are coming soon.

Comment: My local friend is going to take me to a Laksa Shack in one of the big suburban megamalls on Wednesday so I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @hippietrail Madras Lane may be worth a shout http://www.timeoutkl.com/food/reviews/Asam-Laksa-Stall

Comment: @hippietrail Also a similar question was asked http://answers.worldnomads.com/questions/malaysia/3036/where-can-i-find-the-best-traditional-laksa-in-kl This may also help http://simplycheapfood.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/penang-laksa-at-kl.html

Comment: I spent 9 months of my current trip in malaysia, a lot of it in JB so I got to try Johor Laksa several times. Unlike every other kind of laksa I've tried, I find it very disappointing at unpretentious places but it can be yummy when it's just a little bit fancier. Not as bad as the worst curry mees I've had but not as good as good ones (-: I also read online some people insist it's not made with spaghetti, though vastly outnumbered with places saying it is.

Answer (score 4):

Try *Jalan Alor*, it's a traditional street with lots of food stalls where you can find different kinds of cheap authentic Malaysian and Chinese food, Laksa will be among them and you will get to see the picture menus before ordering. You will definitely go there few times to try all different kinds of food. Enjoy!

Check [Wonderful Malaysia](http://www.wonderfulmalaysia.com/food/jalan-alor-food-street.htm) for more information and pictures.

[image: jalan alor 1]

[image: jalan alor 2]

Comment: I walked to Jalan Alor today. Only a couple of places were open before 5.30 and still less than half by the time I left. One end of the road was mostly Thai places and the other mostly Chinese. Only two had signs saying "laksa" and when I asked for it at one they didn't have it. I asked at one with no sign and they said yet but actually served my "curry mee" which I'm glad I also tried, but it wasn't laksa.

Comment: @hippietrail I asked a Malaysian friend, she told me Chinese places sells laksa.

Comment: Yes it was Chinese places I tried today that I just described in the previous comment.

Comment: If memory serves, this area is famous for seafood and is one of the areas I had the most disappointing curry mees a couple of times. I wouldn't recommend it for food other than seafood.